# Dashboard entry restriction using credit card payment

Tags: django

I have an eccomerce system build with Django with some services in the dashbord , I want to restrict some services from those who have not payed through credit card ,though they can login and perform other services which I offer for free,just like AWS or Canva does for premium services.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. one of solutions for that, in user model you can put account_type for
   example, when any user send request you can check account_type and
   apply some restriction
2. when user pay you can check payment status if done update the account_type

Comment: Please if you might have any sample of the source code I can appreciate,